When applying for a job, should I mention that I previously declined a job offer from a sister company?
I have applied for a job at Company "A" a few months ago. The recruitment process went smoothly, and at the end I got a job offer. However, I politely declined the offer, since I also got a better offer from another company (doesn't matter which).
Now, I am applying for a job at Company "B", which happens to be a "sister" company of "A" ("B" is a subsidiary of "A"; both are owned by the same parent company).
Should I mention during the recruitment process at Company "B" that I previously got a job offer from Company "A" ? Would it benefit me in any way ? Or is it better not to mention it at all ?


Should I mention during the recruitment process at Company "B" that I
previously got a job offer from Company "A"? Would it benefit me in
any way? Or is it better not to mention it at all?

Telling me you got an offer from company X in the past tells me nothing. That means for that specific job description, hiring team, and candidates you were selected. I have no idea if you were the best of 20 solid candidates, or the 3rd choice of 5 candidates because the top two already said no.
Even if the offer came from my company, it is a new competition and until I have reviewed all the resumes and conducted all the interviews I have no idea where you rank. That means I have to evaluate your application to see  if you will meet the requirements.
Remember anything you put in your resume, application, and cover letter can be the source of a question. If you make too big of a deal about the previous offer, I might have some questions regarding why you rejected the offer.

There's no need to tell them yourself, telling them can limit your chances. However, if they do bring it up, have some sort of explanation prepared for it.

Have an explanation prepared for what ? For why I declined the previous offer ? Or ?

Yes, for why you declined. It can be as simple as "It didn't feel like the right fit" or "I had my eye on a better offer" or even "yeah. in retrospect that might have been a mistake."  Just answer honestly; unless your answer is " because I wasn't desperate yet" it's an interesting but unimportant detail.
